# How can I extract colon separated key values with optional occurances from a string (Javascript regex)?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text which looks like this:

> Last years budget **%%table name:budget year:last%%** was based on **%%tablename:expenses%%**.
>
> This years budget **%%table name:budget year:current%% approved:no** is based on
>   **%%table name:expenses type:forecast%%**

The word **table** is always there. All colon separated key-value pairs are optional.

My approach to solve extraction was

```
/%%table( *(\S+):(\S+) *)*%%/mg
```

But this expression only returns the last key:value pair per match. Here's the example code:

https://regex101.com/r/mqDoFU/1

Comment: I apologize, but I believe the regex101 example contains the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The capturing group will [always capture the last iteration](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html).

You have to iterate over the string:

```js
var mystring = 'Last years budget %%table name:budget year:last%% was based on %%tablename:expenses%%.'
const re = /(?:%%table )?([^:\s%]+:[^%\s]+)/g;

while (match = re.exec(mystring)) {
   console.log(match[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try an alternate method that uses a regular expression to capture all the tables and then split each one into key / value pairs like this:

```js
const mystring = `Last years budget %%table name:budget year:last%% was based on %%tablename:expenses%%.

This years budget %%table name:budget year:current%% approved:no is based on %%table name:expenses type:forecast%%`

const tables = []

mystring.replace(/%%table((?:\s*\S+:\S+)+)\s*%%/g, (table, entries) => tables.push(entries))

tables.forEach((entries, index, array) => {
  array[index] = entries.trim().split(/\s+/g).map(entry => entry.split(':'))
})

console.log(tables)
```